# Is there a name for this kind of font?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, html

Is there a name for this kind of font that you used to find on cable bulletin boards?

[image: 1980s cable tv bulletin board]

If I wanted to imitate this on a website, which font would you recommend?

Comment: It looks like a screenshot from one of those TV teletext services that were common in the 80's and 90's.  I suspect if you google "teletext font" you'll find something.

Comment: Thanks that actually got me the right font name!

Answer (score 3):

You could try the [Camcorder typeface](https://johansson.design/projects/CamcorderFontFamily/) from Badmeangood. It's a very complete type family by a designer who [really loves](https://johansson.design) the CRT aesthetic.